# how to put two parameters by jquery in a link to use by codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

i want to put two parameters by jquery in href of `a` link and then use by codeigniter, my code is below:

```
$("#user_comment_show").append("<li>"+...+'<a id="remove_link" href="<?php echo base_url().'my_site/remove_user_comment/';?>'+data.user_email_address+"/"+data.user_text+'">'+.....+"</li>"
```

i see data.user_email_address and data.user_text in source page but by select `a` link codeigniter shows me an error :

> The URI you submitted has disallowed characters.

what's wrong with code and how to send these two parameters to my public function in codeigniter by jquery in `a` link. i appreciate to help me solve my problem

> data.user_email_address  &&    data.user_text find by ajax in database

my a link in source page
[image]

Comment: Could you post an example of the URL

Answer (score 0):

change into like this

```
$("#user_comment_show").append("<li><a id='remove_link' href='<?php echo base_url()?>/my_site/remove_user_comment/'+data.user_email_address+'/'+data.user_text+'>Your Link Name</a></li>")
```

hopefully this will work fine.

Comment: i think codeigniter can't accept @ in email address as link and show error as The URI you submitted has disallowed characters.

Comment: then you should allow @ in allowed character go to config file at line number 137 $config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-'; and add @ in this array... if this wont work then reply me